# How to ungroup an array vector in DolphinDB?

Tags: sql, arrays, dolphindb

Using the `toArray` function with the `group by` clause, I grouped the "volume" column by the "ticker" column, and concatenated the grouped values into an array vector.

```
ticker = `AAPL`IBM`IBM`AAPL`AMZN`AAPL`AMZN`IBM`AMZN
volume = 106 115 121 90 130 150 145 123 155;
t = table(ticker, volume);
t;

t1 = select toArray(volume) as volume_all from t group by ticker;
t1;
```

[image]

Now I want to ungroup the array vector, i,e., the “volume_all“ column. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the following script:

```
ticker = `AAPL`IBM`IBM`AAPL`AMZN`AAPL`AMZN`IBM`AMZN
volume = 106 115 121 90 130 150 145 123 155;
t = table(ticker, volume);

t1 = select toArray(volume) as volume_all from t group by ticker;
unionAll(peach(x->table(take(x.ticker,size(x.volume_all)) as ticker, x.volume_all as volume),t1),0)
```

A built-in function `ungroup` will be released in the 2.00.10 version for this purpose.